# tns-core-modules : npmjs (version 1.7.1) vs librairies.io (version 2.0.0-angular.3)

Tags: angular, nativescript

As you can see in the title of the post, I'd like to know why these 2 websites reference 2 different versions of tns-core-modules as the latest and according to you, which one should I use ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest official version of the NativeScript cross-platform modules ([tns-core-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-core-modules)) is 1.7.1. It is the one, published in npmjs.com.

Version 2.0 is under development now and it could be that [libraries.io](https://libraries.io/npm/tns-core-modules) publish unstable/nightly builds. Moreover, they seem to take an angular-specific tag.

By the way, the [NativeScript CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript) itself installs the appropriate cross-platform modules when a new project created. That said, creating a new project is a nice way of verifying which is the latest "official" version of the package.

Cheers,
Erjan